# Sinon fake/stub/spy a class that was exported using 'export type'

Tags: typescript, sinon

I'm using a library to generate Typescript bindings, and it automatically exports the class I'd like to fake/stub/spy using `export type { MyClass } from "./MyClass"`.

The generated `bindings.ts`:

```
export type { MyClass } from "./MyClass";
```

In `index.test.ts`, the following code:

```
sinon.replace(MyClass.prototype, "someFunction", sinon.fake())
```

...throws the compile-time TS error:

```
'MyClass' cannot be used as a value because it was exported using 'export type'.ts(1362)
```

Is there a way to fake/stub/spy `MyClass.someFunction` if it's exported as a type?

Comment: The error is clear. `import type` only imports declarations to be used for type annotations and declarations. It always gets fully erased, so there’s no remnant of it at runtime. Similarly, `export type` only provides an export that can be used for type contexts, and is also erased from TypeScript’s output. So why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2, I'm just realizing that my `.d.ts` files don't get compiled. I need to fake `someFunction` but since `MyClass` is exported as a type, I suppose I need to fake an instance of `MyClass` with `sinon.replace(instance, "someFunction", sinon.fake(instance.someFunction))`. The problem with that is that I get a `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'someFunction' of object '#<MyClass>'`, so I'm stuck.